# Send Data to Wordpress from kiosk

Tags: plugins, api

I need to get a data from kiosk (think specific ATM machine) to wordpress database. Kiosk service providers told me to give them Gateway URL and Request format to send data.

Im stuck on this, I dont know which WP API will be able to do it? What will be the gateway url and what request format will it be.

I just dont know where to start this from. I will need to receive the data, save it in DB and then display the data in custom plugin and run different functions on it. I know how to do all this functions once I receive the data, but Im stuck on the step where I need to give the Kiosk providers the instructions in what format to send data and what will be the gateway URL.

Can you help me with this please? Any directions, where to start and which API to use etc...

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: If they have XML files you could just ask where the XML is located and write a script to read the file and then insert it into wordpress. You can use php cron to check for files as often as needed.

Comment: Hi @gdaniel thanks for response. XML and Cron will not be helpful as far as I know, because it will be time sensitive operation, as soon as they get data on kiosk they should send it immediately. If I did it with Cron it would not be a best solution to run a cron job every min or every 30 secs to check if there is any new data to grab. Besides, I dont even know if they have XML data, I didnt ask for it for the reason that I wrote above. Any other ideas?

Comment: This sounds like important information that likely needs to be secured and backed-up among other things.  I would recommend hiring a professional Dave.

Comment: Have a look to [this example](http://giuseppe-mazzapica.github.io/Cortex/examples/build-restuful-api-wordpress.html) on my plugin Cortex, it can be a starting point. To improve security, ask the kiosk service to give you the IP address or (addresses class) they will use to send you the request, and before saving data check the IP the request comes form.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect candidate for the [WordPress REST API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) It's getting integrated with core in 4.1 I think, but you can use it as a plugin for now.