# Title displaying multiple times

Tags: posts, title, get-the-title, wp-title

I'm facing a problem where my title is being displayed multiple times.

Using the following code the page title 'News' is displayed 10 times, the same number as the number of posts I've elected to display.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if( is_singular() ) { ?>
        <h1 class="row-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <p class="meta">Written By: <?php echo get_the_author() ?><span>&bull;</span><?php the_date(); ?></p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1 class="row-title"><?php wp_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php } endwhile; ?>
```

However, using this version of code, the latest 10 post titles are displayed instead.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if( is_singular() ) { ?>
        <h1 class="row-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <p class="meta">Written By: <?php echo get_the_author() ?><span>&bull;</span><?php the_date(); ?></p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1 class="row-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php } endwhile; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`wp_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) is supposed to be used to generate the text for the title tag:

```
<head>
    <title><?php wp_title();?></title>
    ...
</head>
```

but to display the current post title within the loop, you should instead use the [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) function.

Comment: Hi Birgire, thanks for that.  I'm aware it should be used in the head section but wanted to illustrate that I can get the page title to display as opposed to just the post titles.  However, this still doesn't resolve the problem I'm having of multiple occurrences

Comment: Hi @estin92,  I assumed from your question that when you used the `the_title()` function everything worked as expected but  not when you tried the `wp_title()` function, that  gave you always the same result. I guess I misunderstood your question then - can you please rephrase the problem, thanks ;-)

Comment: Hi @Birgire.  I'll try and break it down as best I can.  On my static posts page I've opted to show 10 recent posts.  My problem is that the title for my page is being displayed 10 times also but with the individual values of each post for that page, archive or category using the second part of code detailed in my original post.

Comment: @estin Please add all that info **directly** to your question in the form of an edit. Thank you

Comment: @estin92 sorry but I'm still confused ;-) I expect `is_singular()` to be `true` on your static front page. What do you expect your code to show on the front page? Can you 1) give the exact HTML source of what you expect to see on the front page and 2) then the HTML source of what you got instead, 3) explaining also what PHP code snippet you used exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

You can use this code.

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Please explain **why** your code should be used, and what is the relevance to the OP. And please correct your mark up

Comment: You can pass attribute in array new WP_Query( $args );
and get what result you want.

Comment: Pieter Goosen, can I ask one question ?

Comment: Feel free to do so :-)

Comment: Kindly give me suggestion for this quetion 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156122/send-data-to-wordpress-from-kiosk

We need also same thing.